# Need advice : Reverse engineering a pdf with shellcode

Tags: malware, vulnerability-analysis, callstack, shellcode

**Problem** :

I try to find the plaintext which was hidden at pdf inbuilt with shellcode

**What i tried** :

I received a pdf which contains javascript with it ,i dig the pdf as follows :

**Exploring  JavaScript inside**:

```
root@kali:~# pdfid APT9001.pdf 
PDFiD 0.0.12 APT9001.pdf
 PDF Header: %PDF-1.5
 obj                   10
 endobj                 9
 stream                 3
 endstream              3
 xref                   2
 trailer                2
 startxref              2
 /Page                  3(2)
 /Encrypt               0
 /ObjStm                0
 /JS                    1(1)
 /JavaScript            1(1)
 /AA                    0
 /OpenAction            1(1)
 /AcroForm              0
 /JBIG2Decode           1(1)
 /RichMedia             0
 /Launch                0
 /EmbeddedFile          0
 /Colors > 2^24         0
```

while extracting  it:

```
root@kali:~# pdf-parser -s javascript APT9001.pdf 
obj 5 0
 Type: /Action
 Referencing: 6 0 R

  <<
    /Type /Action
    /S /JavaScript
    /JS 6 0 R
  >>


root@kali:~# pdf-parser -o 6 APT9001.pdf 
obj 6 0
 Type: 
 Referencing: 
 Contains stream

  <<
    /Length 6170
    /Filter '[  \r\n /Fla#74eDe#63o#64#65  /AS#43IIHexD#65cod#65 ]'
  >>


root@kali:~# pdf-parser -o 6 -d APT9001.js -f APT9001.pdf 
obj 6 0
 Type: 
 Referencing: 
 Contains stream

  <<
    /Length 6170
    /Filter '[  \r\n /Fla#74eDe#63o#64#65  /AS#43IIHexD#65cod#65 ]'
  >>
```

If i open the JavaScript file, i can quickly find the shellcode:

> %u72f9%u4649%u1525%u7f0d%u3d3c%ue084%ud62a%ue139%ua84a%u76b9%u9824%u7378%u7d71%u757f%u2076%u96d4%uba91%u1970%ub8f9%ue232%u467b%u9ba8%ufe01%uc7c6%ue3c1%u7e24%u437c%ue180%ub115%ub3b2%u4f66%u27b6%u9f3c%u7a4e%u412d%ubbbf%u7705%uf528%u9293%u9990%ua998%u0a47%u14eb%u3d49%u484b%u372f%ub98d%u3478%u0bb4%ud5d2%ue031%u3572%ud610%u6740%u2bbe%u4afd%u041c%u3f97%ufc3a%u7479%u421d%ub7b5%u0c2c%u130d%u25f8%u76b0%u4e79%u7bb1%u0c66%u2dbb%u911c%ua92f%ub82c%u8db0%u0d7e%u3b96%u49d4%ud56b%u03b7%ue1f7%u467d%u77b9%u3d42%u111d%u67e0%u4b92%ueb85%u2471%u9b48%uf902%u4f15%u04ba%ue300%u8727%u9fd6%u4770%u187a%u73e2%ufd1b%u2574%u437c%u4190%u97b6%u1499%u783c%u8337%ub3f8%u7235%u693f%u98f5%u7fbe%u4a75%ub493%ub5a8%u21bf%ufcd0%u3440%u057b%ub2b2%u7c71%u814e%u22e1%u04eb%u884a%u2ce2%u492d%u8d42%u75b3%uf523%u727f%ufc0b%u0197%ud3f7%u90f9%u41be%ua81c%u7d25%ub135%u7978%uf80a%ufd32%u769b%u921d%ubbb4%u77b8%u707e%u4073%u0c7a%ud689%u2491%u1446%u9fba%uc087%u0dd4%u4bb0%ub62f%ue381%u0574%u3fb9%u1b67%u93d5%u8396%u66e0%u47b5%u98b7%u153c%ua934%u3748%u3d27%u4f75%u8cbf%u43e2%ub899%u3873%u7deb%u257a%uf985%ubb8d%u7f91%u9667%ub292%u4879%u4a3c%ud433%u97a9%u377e%ub347%u933d%u0524%u9f3f%ue139%u3571%u23b4%ua8d6%u8814%uf8d1%u4272%u76ba%ufd08%ube41%ub54b%u150d%u4377%u1174%u78e3%ue020%u041c%u40bf%ud510%ub727%u70b1%uf52b%u222f%u4efc%u989b%u901d%ub62c%u4f7c%u342d%u0c66%ub099%u7b49%u787a%u7f7e%u7d73%ub946%ub091%u928d%u90bf%u21b7%ue0f6%u134b%u29f5%u67eb%u2577%ue186%u2a05%u66d6%ua8b9%u1535%u4296%u3498%ub199%ub4ba%ub52c%uf812%u4f93%u7b76%u3079%ubefd%u3f71%u4e40%u7cb3%u2775%ue209%u4324%u0c70%u182d%u02e3%u4af9%ubb47%u41b6%u729f%u9748%ud480%ud528%u749b%u1c3c%ufc84%u497d%u7eb8%ud26b%u1de0%u0d76%u3174%u14eb%u3770%u71a9%u723d%ub246%u2f78%u047f%ub6a9%u1c7b%u3a73%u3ce1%u19be%u34f9%ud500%u037a%ue2f8%ub024%ufd4e%u3d79%u7596%u9b15%u7c49%ub42f%u9f4f%u4799%uc13b%ue3d0%u4014%u903f%u41bf%u4397%ub88d%ub548%u0d77%u4ab2%u2d93%u9267%ub198%ufc1a%ud4b9%ub32c%ubaf5%u690c%u91d6%u04a8%u1dbb%u4666%u2505%u35b7%u3742%u4b27%ufc90%ud233%u30b2%uff64%u5a32%u528b%u8b0c%u1452%u728b%u3328%ub1c9%u3318%u33ff%uacc0%u613c%u027c%u202c%ucfc1%u030d%ue2f8%u81f0%u5bff%u4abc%u8b6a%u105a%u128b%uda75%u538b%u033c%uffd3%u3472%u528b%u0378%u8bd3%u2072%uf303%uc933%uad41%uc303%u3881%u6547%u5074%uf475%u7881%u7204%u636f%u7541%u81eb%u0878%u6464%u6572%ue275%u8b49%u2472%uf303%u8b66%u4e0c%u728b%u031c%u8bf3%u8e14%ud303%u3352%u57ff%u6168%u7972%u6841%u694c%u7262%u4c68%u616f%u5464%uff53%u68d2%u3233%u0101%u8966%u247c%u6802%u7375%u7265%uff54%u68d0%u786f%u0141%udf8b%u5c88%u0324%u6168%u6567%u6842%u654d%u7373%u5054%u54ff%u2c24%u6857%u2144%u2121%u4f68%u4e57%u8b45%ue8dc%u0000%u0000%u148b%u8124%u0b72%ua316%u32fb%u7968%ubece%u8132%u1772%u45ae%u48cf%uc168%ue12b%u812b%u2372%u3610%ud29f%u7168%ufa44%u81ff%u2f72%ua9f7%u0ca9%u8468%ucfe9%u8160%u3b72%u93be%u43a9%ud268%u98a3%u8137%u4772%u8a82%u3b62%uef68%u11a4%u814b%u5372%u47d6%uccc0%ube68%ua469%u81ff%u5f72%ucaa3%u3154%ud468%u65ab%u8b52%u57cc%u5153%u8b57%u89f1%u83f7%u1ec7%ufe39%u0b7d%u3681%u4542%u4645%uc683%ueb04%ufff1%u68d0%u7365%u0173%udf8b%u5c88%u0324%u5068%u6f72%u6863%u7845%u7469%uff54%u2474%uff40%u2454%u5740%ud0ff

Now i am stucked with this part ,now how can i explore further :

the possible solutions which i might think were

convert these shellcode to exe and exporting it as txt 
once the text was recovered exploring the stack of it{assumption]

am i on right way?or any community ideas to reverse engineer these further?

Comment: they look like a bunch of unicode characters !

Comment: http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/hacking-pdf-part-1/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shellcode is [unicode escaped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape). You can convert it to its hex representation using a simple python script.

```
from binascii import unhexlify as unhx

encoded = open('encoded.txt').read() # The shellcode dump
out = open('shellcode.bin', 'wb')

for s in encoded.split('%'):
    if len(s) == 5:
        HI_BYTE = s[3:]
        LO_BYTE = s[1:3]
        out.write(unhx(HI_BYTE))
        out.write(unhx(LO_BYTE))
out.close()
```

*shellcode.bin* contains the shellcode in its binary form. You can convert the shellcode to an executable using the following C template or using an online tool such as [this](http://sandsprite.com/shellcode_2_exe.php)

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char payload[] = 
{
//Bytes of the shellcode
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    (*(void (*)()) payload)();
    return(0);
}
```

Running the resultant executable produces this output.

[image]

Comment: owned by a pdf , hahaha good exploit

Answer (score 1):

The answer by extreme coders was wonderful,i wish to share my method too over here:

I convert it to an executable with the tools in REMnux:

```
remnux@remnux:~$ unicode2hex-escaped < sc.txt > sc2.txt
remnux@remnux:~$ shellcode2exe -s sc2.txt 


Reading string shellcode from file sc2.txt
Generating executable file
Writing file sc2.exe
Done.
remnux@remnux:~$
```

The shellcode puts something on the stack:

[image]

If i split it and observe carefully :

[image]

So my guessed answer would be wa1ch.d3m.spl01ts@flare-on.com